# AOT Compilation error in angular library

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-compiler-cli

I Made a library for Angular 2 but I am stuck in [this issue](https://github.com/JulioWar/jw-bootstrap-switch-ng2/issues/4).

I am getting this error:

```
ERROR in C:/xampp/htdocs/github/jw-bootstrap-switch-ng2/switch-project/src/$$_gendir/node_modules/jw-bootstrap-switch-ng2/src/directive.ngfactory.ts (246,59): Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'boolean'.
```

and I don't understand what it's wrong in my code.

you can review my code on Github [here](https://github.com/JulioWar/jw-bootstrap-switch-ng2)

If anyone have more experience in this issue please let me know. I will appreciate your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting error in factory within this code

```
this.context.value.subscribe(_eventHandler.bind(view,'value')));
```

It means that you have `output` property with name `value`

```
@Component({
    selector: 'bSwitch',
    outputs: ['value'],
```

but in the same time i see:

```
get value(): boolean {
    return this._innerState;
};

set value(v: boolean) {
    if (v === null || typeof v === "undefined") this._indeterminate = true;
    this.setStateValue(v);
}
```

So i would remove

```
outputs: ['value'],
```

Comment: Thanks @yurzui, but where did you find this `this.context.value.subscribe(_eventHandler.bind(view,'value')));`